# Remove from html string all the empty rows and columns in tables by regex

Tags: javascript, html, string

I try to write a function that remove from **minify** htmlString all the empty rows and columns in the tables.

the formatted htmlString (for the order):

```
<h2>lorem</h2>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

for example:

```
let htmlString =
`
<h2>lorem</h2><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Company</th><th></th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td></td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td></td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
`
// complex example:
let htmlString2 =
`
<table><thead><tr><th><p>xyz</p></th><th></th><th><p><strong>2019</strong></p></th><th><p><strong>2018</strong></p></th><th></th></tr><tr><th></th><th></th><th><p><strong>xyz</strong></p></th><th colspan="2"><p><strong>xyz</strong></p></th></tr><tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><p><strong>x</strong></p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td><p><strong>xyz</strong></p></td><td></td><td><p><strong>359,423</strong></p></td><td><p>349,380</p></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
`

const removeEmptyColumnAndRow = (htmlString ) => {
//empty rows and columns 

return htmlString ;
}
console.log( removeEmptyColumAndRow(htmlString ) )
```

output excepted:

```
<h2>lorem</h2><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Company</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Mexico</td></tr></table><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a [DOM Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead of regex. [Parse the string to a document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString), and then remove the empty elements that you don't need.

```js
const str = '<h2>lorem</h2><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Company</th><th></th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td></td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td></td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table><p>Lorem ipsum dolor quas!</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>';

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

function removeEmpty(doc, type) {
  const els = doc.querySelectorAll(type);
  els.forEach(el => {
    if (el.textContent === '') el.remove();
  });
  return doc;
}

const els = ['td', 'th', 'tr'];

for (const el of els) {
  removeEmpty(doc, el);
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', doc.body.innerHTML);

console.log(doc.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: It does not work. The position of the cells is incorrect. The countries are not under the "country" column

Comment: @roi I missed the `<th>` element. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks, it works with the first example. unfortunately in the complex example (look for htmlString2) it doesn't work.

Comment: Try swapping the `th` and the `tr` around: `const els = ['td', 'th', 'tr'];`. Does that work? @roi

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it is working. @roi. [The first table is the original, the second one the table after processing.](https://pastebin.com/QuRP8TTj)

Comment: it does not work in the complex example